# How can I deploy to Google App Engine an app that depends on a yarn workspaces without publishing the packages to a npm registry?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am currently migrating our monorepo to yarn workspaces. It contains multiple packages and services. Services depends on packages in their respective `package.json`. I would like to deploy my services to Google App Engine without having to publish the packages to a private npm registry.

I managed to deploy a single service by using a custom runtime and by moving the `app.yaml` and the `Dockerfile` to the root of the monorepo in order to have access to the packages and the service in the build context. The issue is that I have multiple services and I cannot have all the dockerfiles at the root of the monorepo, as they have to be named `Dockerfile` and that I cannot change the build context.

I see 2 naive solutions:

The first would be to move the `app.yaml` and `Dockerfile` of the corresponding service to the root of the monorepo before deploying. But this looks quite dirty and would make the CI code very complicated.

The second would be to have a single `Dockerfile` and `service1.yaml`, `service2.yaml` etc. at the root of the monorepo and to pass variables to the Dockerfile. The problem is that I don't see any way in App Engine documentation to pass variables to the `Dockerfile` of a custom runtime.

My dream solution would be to be able to keep each `Dockerfile` and `app.yaml` in the directory of their respective services and to be able to set the build context through the `gcloud` CLI (like we can do in `docker-compose`).
Example:

```
project
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── package1
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── src
│   ├── package2
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── src
│   └── package3
│       ├── package.json
│       └── src
├── services
│   ├── service1
│   │   ├── app.yaml
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── src
│   └── service2
│       ├── app.yaml
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       ├── package.json
│       └── src
└── yarn.lock
```

and run something like: `gcloud app deploy services/service1/app.yaml --build-context=.`

But I don't see any way of doing this in the documentation.

Do you know how I can get closer to my "dream solution"?

Comment: What about building the Docker images beforehand (even with docker-compose) and pushing them to `gcr.io` (Google Container Registry) so these can be used on deploy time with the `--image-url` [option](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--image-url)?

Comment: @bhito I didn't think of doing it this way but that could work. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could be of help, I will add it as an answer to give it more visibility to the community :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding possible option suggested in comments to give more visibility.

One possibility would be keeping the `docker-compose` workflow that you were using and integrate it with your App Engine deploys.

As you were already building your docker images with `docker-compose` in order to specify the build context, you can [push](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#pushing_an_image_to_a_registry) the result of the build operations to Google's Container Registry so the images can be later used to deploy App Engine by using the `--image-url` [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--image-url).